# How set manufacturer via web service in Prestashop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

It seems to be a stupid question, but i need to set via web service, my product, quantity and manufacturer.
There is no more documentation in web about this.

When i insert a product to prestashop via web service , it's important declare:

```
unset($resources->position_in_category);
unset($resources->manufacturer_name);
unset($resources->quantity);
```

Only in this way, it's works.
Now, i found a solution to set quantity, but nothing about manufacturer.

Can Someone help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Get the manufacturer ID and in Products resource, assign it by:

```
$resources-> id_manufacturer = MANUFACTURER_ID
```

Example on getting Manufacturer ID by its name

```
function GetManufacturerID($name) {
    try {
        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
        $opt = array(
            'resource' =>'manufacturers',
            'display'  => '[id]',
            'filter[name]'  => $name);      
        $xml = $webService->get($opt);          
        return $xml->children()->children()->manufacturer->id;
    }   catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)    {       
            $trace = $e->getTrace();
    }   
}
```

Example to add new manufacturer

```
function AddManufacturer($manu_name) {  
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $xml = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'manufacturers?schema=synopsis'));
    $resources = $xml->children()->children();
    $resources->name = $manu_name;  
    $resources->active = 1; 
    unset($resources -> link_rewrite);

    $webService->add(
        array(
        'resource' => 'manufacturers',
        'active' => array(),
        'postXml' => $xml->asXML()
        )
    );
}
```